# Importing R package using rpy2

Tags: python, r, rpy2

I'm trying to use the R (Version 3.4.3) package MICE in Python 3.6.5 with rpy2.
This is the code I use:

```
import os
os.environ['R_HOME'] = 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3'
os.environ['R_USER'] = 'C:/Users/username/Anaconda3/Lib/site-packages/rpy2' 
import rpy2.robjects as ro
from rpy2.robjects.packages import importr
mice = importr('mice', lib_loc ='C:\Program Files\R\R-3.4.3\library')
```

When I execute this, my Jupyter notebook dies. In the terminal I get the error message:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'stats' in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...):
unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found.
During startup - Warning message:
package 'stats' in options("defaultPackages") was not found
Error: '\P' is an unrecognized escape in character string starting ""C:\P"
```

But I do have the package stats installed and the file 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll' exists.
Does anybody know a solution for this problem?

I installed the package mice in RStudio. I made sure that all my installed R libraries are in the directory C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/library so that dependencies of mice are found in the same folder. For this I just copied all the packages installed in another folder to that one (I hope that's not a problem?)

Comment: Double the backslashes: `C:\\Program Files\\R …`

Comment: It still dies...

Comment: I now also tried writing `lib_loc ='C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/library`
I get the same error message as in the terminal before: `RRuntimeError: Error in inDL(x, as.logical(local), as.logical(now), ...) : 
  unable to load shared object 'C:/Program Files/R/R-3.4.3/library/stats/libs/x64/stats.dll':
  LoadLibrary failure:  The specified module could not be found`

Comment: That looks to be an R error. At command line (cmd or PowerShell), enter the R shell (usually just type `Rterm`) and type `library(mice, lib.loc='C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.4.3\\library')`. Check the output. Also, you should not manually move materials. Use *lib* arg: `install.packages("mice", lib="C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.4.3\\library")`

Comment: It didn't work with PowerShell, so I just looked for Rterm.exe in my R-3.4.3 folder and opened it. That should work the same, right? When I typed in `library('mice', lib.loc='C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.4.3\\library')` I got the same output that I always get when loading mice into R: `Loading required package: lattice

Attaching package: 'mice'

The following objects are masked from 'package:base':

    cbind, rbind

Warning message:
package 'mice' was built under R version 3.4.4`